# What is the difference between ZoneOffset.UTC and ZoneId.of("UTC")?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

Why does

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
System.out.println(now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
        .equals(now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"))));
```

print out `false`?

I would expect the both `ZonedDateTime` instances to be equal.

Comment: I started a follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69972061

Answer (score 274, accepted):

The answer comes from the [javadoc of `ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) (emphasis mine) ...

> A ZoneId is used to identify the rules used to convert between an
>   Instant and a LocalDateTime. There are two distinct types of ID:
>
> - Fixed offsets - a fully resolved offset from UTC/Greenwich, that uses the same offset for all local date-times
> - Geographical regions - an area where a specific set of rules for finding the offset from UTC/Greenwich apply
>
> Most fixed offsets are represented by ZoneOffset. **Calling normalized()
>   on any ZoneId will ensure that a fixed offset ID will be represented
>   as a ZoneOffset.**

... and from the [javadoc of `ZoneId#of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-) (emphasis mine):

> This method parses the ID producing a ZoneId or ZoneOffset. **A
>   ZoneOffset is returned if the ID is 'Z', or starts with '+' or '-'**.

The argument id is specified as `"UTC"`, therefore it will return a `ZoneId` with an offset, which also presented in the string form:

```
System.out.println(now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
System.out.println(now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")));
```

*Outputs:*

```
2017-03-10T08:06:28.045Z
2017-03-10T08:06:28.045Z[UTC]
```

As you use the `equals` method for comparison, you **check for object equivalence**. Because of the described difference, the result of the evaluation is `false`.

When the [`normalized()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#normalized--) method is used as proposed in the documentation, the comparison using `equals` will return `true`, as `normalized()` will return the corresponding `ZoneOffset`:

> Normalizes the time-zone ID, returning a ZoneOffset where possible.

```
now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    .equals(now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC").normalized())); // true
```

As the documentation states, if you use `"Z"` or `"+0"` as input id, `of` will return the `ZoneOffset` directly and there is no need to call `normalized()`:

```
now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).equals(now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Z"))); //true
now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).equals(now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("+0"))); //true
```

---

To check **if they store the same date time**, you can use the [`isEqual`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#isEqual-java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime-) method instead:

```
now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    .isEqual(now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"))); // true
```

---

**Sample**

```
System.out.println("equals - ZoneId.of(\"UTC\"): " + nowZoneOffset
        .equals(now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"))));
System.out.println("equals - ZoneId.of(\"UTC\").normalized(): " + nowZoneOffset
        .equals(now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC").normalized())));
System.out.println("equals - ZoneId.of(\"Z\"): " + nowZoneOffset
        .equals(now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Z"))));
System.out.println("equals - ZoneId.of(\"+0\"): " + nowZoneOffset
        .equals(now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("+0"))));
System.out.println("isEqual - ZoneId.of(\"UTC\"): "+ nowZoneOffset
        .isEqual(now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"))));
```

*Output:*

```
equals - ZoneId.of("UTC"): false
equals - ZoneId.of("UTC").normalized(): true
equals - ZoneId.of("Z"): true
equals - ZoneId.of("+0"): true
isEqual - ZoneId.of("UTC"): true
```

Comment: The docs also say "If the zone ID equals 'GMT', 'UTC' or 'UT' then the result is a ZoneId with the same ID and rules equivalent to ZoneOffset.UTC". Same ID and rules, but different behaviour. `ZoneId.of("Z")` gives you `ZoneOffset.UTC` but `ZoneId.of("UTC")` gives you a `ZoneId` (that is not `ZoneOffset.UTC`). This API is unintuitive, to say the least.

Comment: ...the API is disaster.

Comment: good gravy. time is hard.I'm sure the next time library in Java will get it right though..... right? right?!?