# Is there any reason to use ZoneId.of("UTC") instead of ZoneOffset.UTC?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, utc

### Is there any reason to use `ZoneId.of("UTC")` instead of `ZoneOffset.UTC`?

We know the difference between the two as provided in [What is the difference between ZoneOffset.UTC and ZoneId.of("UTC")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506891/why-is-zoneoffset-utc-zoneid-ofutc).

<tl;dr> version:

- `ZoneOffset.UTC` returns a mere `ZoneOffset` with ID "Z", offset of 0 and default zone rules.
- `ZoneId.of("UTC")` returns a `ZoneRegion` with ID "UTC" and `ZoneOffset.UTC` included.

</tl;dr>

For this question, I assume UTC-usage merely for easier date and time handling and not, because something might actually be located in the UTC region or some other business reason to have this as the actual ZoneRegion.

For example, when dealing with `ZonedDateTime`. The only difference I could find was that it prints differently.

```
2021-06-10T15:28:25.000000111Z
2021-06-10T15:28:25.000000111Z[UTC]
```

We are having code review discussions back and forth about this, so I guess this conflict is not uncommon.

### Here are my thoughts so far

#### `ZoneOffset.UTC`

- It is a constant (and further, it's Offset value (0) is even cached).
- It has (a tiny bit) less overhead, due to the missing region information.
- At UTC, there are no daylight saving times or historical shifts to consider, like in any other timezone.
  Thus, an Offset of 0 is in general enough for all use cases I encountered so far (like converting to and from a certain Zone Region with a particular daylight saving status).

#### `ZoneId.of("UTC")`

- In general, I'd say ZoneRegions are preferred to ZoneOffsets, due to a range of additional location-specific data like a particular daylight saving time or time shifts in history.
- However, in case of UTC, `ZoneId.of("UTC")` is just a region wrap around `ZoneOffset.UTC` and I could not find any benefit so far. As far as I know, in UTC no region-relevant data exists apart from it's inherited `ZoneOffset.UTC` rules.
- Needs to be parsed every time.

---

### So my *_guess_* is:

Unless you really need the UTC time zone/region for some (e.g. business) reasons, you should prefer `ZoneOffset.UTC`. It has a (minor) advantage in its performance footprint and the UTC ZoneRegion does not seem provide any benefit I can see or think of.

However, because of the complexity of the Java Date Time API it is hard to tell if I am missing something in this discussion.
**Is there any reason why someone should ever use `ZoneId.of("UTC")`?**

Comment: I agree with your guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of one situation where `ZoneId.of("UTC")` might be preferable over `ZoneOffset.UTC`. If you use **jackson-modules-java8** to deserialize `ZonedDataTime` from JSON, you get dates with `ZoneId`.

For example, let's say we have this POJO (getters/setters omitted for brevity):

```java
class Example {
    private ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
}
```

If you print an instance of the class you get:

```java
Example example1 = new Example();
System.out.println(example1);

// output:
// Example(date=2022-06-17T00:00Z) - as expected
```

What happens when you deserialize JSON containing the above string `2022-06-17T00:00Z`?

```java
String json = "{\"date\":\"2022-06-17T00:00Z\"}";
Example example2 = mapper.readValue(json, Example.class);
System.out.println(example2);
// output:
// Example(date=2022-06-17T00:00Z[UTC]) // now with ZoneId(!)
```

So now we have two variants, one with `ZoneOffset` and one with `ZoneId`:

- `2022-06-17T00:00Z`
- `2022-06-17T00:00Z[UTC]`

And these are not equal to each other. For example:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
ZonedDateTime z1 = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime z2 = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("UTC"));

System.out.println(z1.equals(z2)); // => false
```

As a result `example1.equals(example2)` will also be `false`. This could be a source of subtle bugs.

**Note**: you get same result if your serialize `new Example()` to a JSON string and deseralize the string back to an object. You will get a date with `ZoneId`.

Tested with Jackson `2.13.1`.

---

**Edit**: I ended up filing a bug for this issue: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/issues/244

Comment: This information is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: My 2 cents: there is also [Etc/UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#UTC) that is the canonical name for UTC time zone according to IANA registry. According to this registry `UTC` and some other names (7 at the moment) are just links to this `Etc/UTC` zone. So, they are basically the same time zone. But `ZoneId` is implemented in a way that considers them as different. `ZonedDateTime` with same instant but different variants of UTC ZoneId will also be different (not equal). So, unfortunately, the problem is broader than just `ZoneOffset.UTC` vs `ZoneId.of("UTC")`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any reason why someone should ever use ZoneId.of("UTC")?

I cannot (right now) think of any **good** reasons.

However, it is not egregiously bad to do that.  There would most likely be a small runtime cost in doing the lookup, but it is unlikely to matter.  And the two forms are (IMO) equally readable.

---

However, if the zone name is parameter you could find code like this:

```
   String zoneName = "UTC";  // my default
   // Try to get a non-default zone
   // ...
   id = ZoneId.of(zoneName);
```

which would (IMO) be better than this:

```
   String zoneName = null;
   // Try to get a non-default zone
   // ...
   id = zoneName == null ? ZoneId.UTC : ZoneId.of(zoneName);
```