# What is the difference between UTC (ZoneId) and (ZoneOffSet)

Tags: java, groovy, spock, utc, zoneddatetime

Out of curiosity are there any one who knows what the difference is between UTC as ZoneId and ZoneOffset in Java.

I was a little bit surprised that it was not true when comparing utc in zoneid and zoneoffset

I tried to write this test in spock and the only thing I could find was that the zone is different.

And does anyone have any recommendation on which one to use when?

It is not clear from the example but I actually used spock/groovy  where == corresponds to the equals method in java, so apoligize for that

But no matter if I would have written lhs.equals(rhs) it would still return false

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now() // 2023-11-03T19:42:41.772234517
ZonedDateTime lhs = now.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC) 
String lhsString = lhs.toString() // 2023-11-03T19:42:41.772234517Z
ZonedDateTime rhs = now.atZone(ZoneId.of('UTC'))
String rhsString = rhs.toString()  // 2023-11-03T19:42:41.772234517Z[UTC]
Duration duration = Duration.between(lhs, rhs)  // PT0S
boolean equal = lhs == rhs   // this is false
```

Comment: BTW comparing reference types (objects) using `==` is often (almost always) an error... it is just comparing the reference, not the *content* - I would expect that even `now.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC) == now.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)` will return `false`, despite `now.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).equals( now.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC) )` being `true`

Comment: ( even in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) of `ZonedDateTime`: "The `equals` method should be used for comparisons." )

Comment: If you're using Spock, this is Groovy not Java, correct?

Comment: @sören you are right this is written in groovy most likely that is why i got a negative response. But == in groovy is the same as equals method in java

Comment: @user85421 it was not clear that the code was written in groovy  so the == is considered the same as equals in java.

Comment: I hope I have added the correct tags to *represent* your problem :-/

Comment: Why are so many people obsessing about `==`, if they don't even speak Groovy? 

Comment: @kriegaex because there was *no information about this being Groovy* and has initially only tagged with [[tag:java]]. I find it surprising you are dismayed that question that *has not been* tagged with the Groovy tag, doesn't mention Groovy, and asks about Java (even using the Java tag) is perceived to be about the semantics of `==` in Java.

Comment: The OP said that he tested with Spock, which, despite missing tags, implies Groovy and, well, Spock. People could just read the whole question...

Comment: @kriegaex so every Java developer must know that Spock is Groovy??? And also that `==` in Groovy, is `equals` in Java??? Not sure why you call trying to help "obsessing". But I would like to point you to the description of the [Comment Everywhere Privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), in special the last *section*.

Comment: No, of course not every developer must know. But when reading a question and meeting something she does not know - say a library, tool or technology - she should spare herself the embarrassment of writing a nonsense answer or comment by exerting at least minimal effort to google that, instead of simply allowing herself to be triggered by a cursory glance at a code snippet, falsely believing she knows what is wrong with it.  Like so often in life, also in programming it is about three things: context, context and context. 

Comment: I am in no way ridiculing people who are trying to help others. Even a faulty try is commendable, I am totally with you there. But maybe some more care and research are helpful in order to avoid confusing OPs more than helping them. Put yourself in the position of an OP for a minute: He has a problem he cannot solve without help, so he is confused already.

Answer (score 2):

The *double-equal* *[equality operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)* will simply compare, in this case, the *instance* of the object.

Since *lhs*, and *rhs*, are assigned different *instances*, the values will return *false*.

Typically, the *[Object#equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))* method will return whether the content is equal.

```java
boolean equal = lhs.equals(rhs)
```

If not, implement your own comparison method.

Comment: Note that OP is using Groovy, where == *does* call .equals()

Comment: You are right if it was java (but I was not clear on that. Apology for that).

Answer (score 2):

Quoting my own comment:

> Z is just a military equivalent to UTC, and the `equals` method should be a bit more precise there. When debugging into the JDK, in the end it boils down to a comparison of two zone IDs, and the fact that `"UTC".equals("Z")` evaluates to `false`. The JDK itself uses both in different contexts, so it also should know that they are equivalent.

Having said that, your workaround is to use `ZoneId.normalized()`:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q77419050

import spock.lang.Specification

import java.time.Duration
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.ZoneOffset
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

class TimeZoneTest extends Specification {
  def test() {
    given:
    def now = LocalDateTime.now()
    
    when:
    def lhs = now.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC.normalized())
    def rhs = now.atZone(ZoneId.of('UTC').normalized())
    def timeDifference = Duration.between(lhs, rhs).get(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)

    then:
    lhs == rhs
    timeDifference == 0
  }
}
```

Try it in the Groovy Web Console,

- either the [simple version](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eNp1kMFOAjEQhu99it7oJmaCiYZowon1QGLkAFy8mNqdLpVuu7YDazS8u-0SQQQvTWf--Wb-mVaqtayRVwhRhU3z0shIGCBSEvwWg7a-g_fR6Ob6bng7ZMw0rQ_EY-vVGqx0NcxbVEYbJcl4dyh4k1sJZBqEchP20pny6JW0pSRcpOhcfvYOp9Xl_EzriHSuEeaMtDBZBe_80hliTFkZI89DMrrASBw_CF0V-Yl5_sV4uoTmlEpE0Yec12aL7r7_Zs35jo_5iXVIOVH0Ff3TrX4DdhUTkEpAUp4vjv5huZgkODTSmk-sRFEcqHCJmlbgtRgkalD8w-UrlEZrDOgUphY_54dXpA7RieTnKrcvoEYSxzvB_GEyeyrnBeub0WGJfoFxRvbCnwljPkz5Hduxb9_xw64) printed above
- or the [more verbose version](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eNqtU8Fu2zAMvfsruFNsoBVSoEWxATnFOxgo2kPSSy-DJtGuVltyJSUZMvTfR9lZVMdOgQ07knx875GUWi5eeIUgkTlhN823hjuPljlPBbNFW9Zmx15vb6-vPs9v5kmimtZYD6414oXVXFds1aJQpRLcK6OPgB98y5lXDbJ8Y_vSqHJnBK9z7nFN0bj8ZDQWcjr_UJYO_bjmMWR4zZbP1mjzqJVPElFz5yCIhNY1Og_406OWDgbm4VcCtIkSPEHSrAsBKrVF_QVmYmMtag91cA2SbF8GSeBawuN6CXviBqVLY5uObdZ1BzptdrCAwbSMcml2ROyPIxEwzseId4Ap5KFeSGbKdEb1WZZ0kN1z79I0LbdKV6SqL3UwU6s9yq5dRtsOyGjv2fTCW8f6uMgH1p_ee6OYcR9SafScncI7myfQQkZYMJCrskRaqEDC_nkj7Dv6HaJOB7oXkTdjFfo0Hpetvi4f7vPVYQm-X8JoVtmJkbZrlUfYozWdiUMhuOhnHs77aRGVe_4T4wuYn93-_9z8fWQ7cwMWBdNs4iAfMdBjGnf_5Y0i_8WU6D_ejVv6UpJ-Hf3QeuJC76daTOmevRrAW_KW_AaHsLaF) with comments, showcasing both the equal and non-equal variants.

More details can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39507023/1082681).

Comment: Please note my update, linking to a more verbose Groovy Web Console example.

Comment: Thanks that is the answer i was looking for. Maybe an OT thing but I can't figure out any use case where it would make sense to disregard them as being equal. It would be a bit like saying 0x10 is not the same as 16 just because they are written in hex and dec format. IMHO. But I guess one has too accept those quirks amongst the other one that  are there in the language.

Answer (score 1):

From the [ZoneId documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html):

> A ZoneId is used to identify the rules used to convert between an Instant and a LocalDateTime.

From the [ZoneOffset documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html):

> Different parts of the world have different time-zone offsets. The rules for how offsets vary by place and time of year are captured in the ZoneId class.
>
> For example, Paris is one hour ahead of Greenwich/UTC in winter and two hours ahead in summer. The ZoneId instance for Paris will reference two ZoneOffset instances - a +01:00 instance for winter, and a +02:00 instance for summer.

So the difference is summer vs winter time (daylight savings time), if the region uses them. There could be different states or countries in the same time zone, for example, Mexico City and Chicago are in the same zone offset (GMT-5), but Mexico stopped switching between summer and winter time in spring of 2023, so during summer they were an hour off, and in winter they'll match again.

So if you want to display or convert to local time, always use the ZoneId which considers the location (state) and the local rules on daylight savings time.

Comment: @JimGarrison Note that OP is using Groovy, where == does call .equals()

Comment: @robert but utc as a timezone what is that and in that case what kind of politics does it have regarding day light saving time and which countries are within. The real issue is that i am running in a 20+ person projekt and people have sometime chosen the timezone and other time chosen the offset causing the issue that even they IMO should be equal they are not.

Comment: @M.A.Tanaka For that reason I'd recommend to always use time stamps in logging in UTC. That makes it much easier to compare / discuss from different locations. UTC is just the location, without daylight savings time, politics, or anything else. UTC is Coordinated Universal Time.

Comment: OTOH, Z is just a military equivalent to UTC, and the `equals` method should be a bit more precise there. When debugging into the JDK, in the end it boils down to a comparison of two zone IDs, and the fact that `"UTC".equals("Z")` evaluates to `false`. The JDK itself uses both in different contexts, so it also should know that they are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks that is what the answer I was looking for